# Problem configuring the MailChimp module

Tags: emails

I am having an issue installing the MailChimp module.  I have installed the module and the extra library under `/sites/all/libraries/mailchimp/MCAPI.class.php`.  I have copy and pasted my API key into the form on `admin/config/services/mailchimp`.  There are no errors coming up in the apache log.  The module is not functional and my lists are not syncing!

In the `MCAPI.class.php` Readme file says this:

> 2) Try running mcapi_lists.php from the command line. Something like
>   this:
>
> ```
> `# php -f mcapi_lists.php`
> ```

But that command is not recognized.

Comment: php command is not recognized or running mcapi_lists.php from the command line is not recognized?

Comment: Bash output:  `Could not open input file: mcapi_lists.php`  PHP is most definitely installed.

Comment: The Mailchimp module has documentation here: https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/mailchimp  If you follow the instructions in the documentation and it still doesn't work, you should search the Mailchimp issue queue and open a support request there.  If this is a module-specific problem and the documentation is insufficient, many other people who use the module will likely have the same problem.

Comment: thats a fair summation of the situation.  i felt the documentation was bit lacking either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out mailchimp was working fine.  The confusion arose in that the mailchimp api doesnt populate the `Lists and Users` tab on my Drupal installation from mailchimp.  Instead it pushes Druapl's mailchimp lists to sync with mailchimp.  The `refresh lists from mailchimp` title can be quite deceiving.